# Which Gzip realization should I use for Scala backend?

Tags: scala, sbt, gzip

I've found two realizations of Gzip encoding, one is Akka realization:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/coding-directives/encodeResponse.html

And other one is sbt-web based realization:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-gzip#sbt-gzip

What are pros and cons of both realizations and which one did you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both implementations you mentioned do totally different things:

akka's implementation dynamically encodes a HTTP response according to the `Accept-Encoding` header of the request whilst the SBT plugin is usefull to gzip static assets when packaging your app (it's a build step).

You cannot compare those implementations, it all depends on what you want to do; choose whatever suits your task.